# If $[G:H\cap K]= [G:H][G:K]$ then $G=HK$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ a finite group and $H,K$ subgroups of $G$. Show that if $[G:H\cap K]= [G:H][G:K]$ then $G=HK$.

I proved that $G=HK$ implies $[G:H\cap K]= [G:H][G:K]$ but not the other direction.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Use the fact that 
$$|HK|=\frac{|H||K|}{|H\cap K|}.$$